# Converting Spark Dataframe to RDD in scala

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am cheking for better approch to convert Dataframe to RDD. Right now I am converting dataframe to collection and looping collection to prepare RDD. But we know looping is not good practice.

```
   val randomProduct = scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[Product]()
   val results = hiveContext.sql("select id,value from  details");
   val collection = results.collect();    
   var i = 0;
   results.collect.foreach(t => {
       val product = new Product(collection(i)(0).asInstanceOf[Long], collection(i)(1).asInstanceOf[String]); 
       i = i+ 1;
       randomProduct += product 
   })

   randomProduct
   //returns RDD[Product]
```

Please suggest me to make it standard & stable format which works for huge amount of data.

Comment: First huge amount of data and collect are not very good friends, Secondly Loop, why ? What is it you are trying to do : "Converting + ??? " ?

Comment: Thanks eliasah. I need RDD[Product] which I will use it to apply some rules on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
val results = hiveContext.sql("select id,value from  details");
results.rdd.map( row => new Product( row.getLong(0), row.getString(1) ) ) // RDD[Product]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Now it is retuning `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[com.cloudera.mypacl.Product]  but required is 
scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[com.cloudera.mypack.Product]` Is there a way where we can convert it to `scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[com.cloudera.mypack.Product]`

Comment: you don't want to do that. a mutable list is a local in-memory structure, not remotely suitable to huge amounts of data. if this is going to be large, you want to keep it as an RDD.

Comment: Thanks Steve. you are correct.  Now I can able to use RDD without converting.

Comment: Is there a way to create RDD without specifying datatype for each column, e.g when we have a huge number of columns?